# UIActivityViewController Copy copies item twice on iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift3, ios11, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to share a webview url on `iOS 11` and when using `Copy` then go to Messages app then paste, it is pasted twice.

Out of curiosity I tried to do the same with Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and also for other apps than messages. The result was interesting:

- Coping from Safari always works in any app
- Coping from Chrome or FireFox works in Notes app, but it duplicates the copied text in any app that has TextField (Messages, WhatsApp, Slack, Signal,...)

Here is my simple code

```
func shareURL(title: String, url: URL) {
    var activityItems = [AnyObject]()
    activityItems.append(TitleActivityItemProvider(title: title))

    activityItems.append(url as AnyObject)

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and here is the `TitleActivityItemProvider` class

```
class TitleActivityItemProvider: UIActivityItemProvider {
    static let activityTypesToIgnore = [UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard]

    init(title: String) {
        super.init(placeholderItem: title)
    }

    override var item : Any {
        if let activityType = activityType {
            if TitleActivityItemProvider.activityTypesToIgnore.contains(activityType) {
                return NSNull()
            }
        }
        return placeholderItem! as AnyObject
    }

    override func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> String {
        return placeholderItem as! String
    }
}
```

is it a bug on `iOS 11` or should I consider doing specific change when working with `UIActivityViewController`

**==UPDATE==**

I noticed when I comment adding `TitleActivityItemProvider` it works fine and when I add it, it duplicates the url however I ignore `UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard` in the title provider and return `NSNull()`

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed it by using `url.absoluteString` when adding item to `activityItems`

```
activityItems.append(url.absoluteString as AnyObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing on the Simulator? On the simulator I had this issue, but on device it only pastes once.

Comment: I have it in both Simulator and device